# Json doesn't output anything

Tags: java, xml, json, spring, maven

I am very new to spring framwework and building rest web services.. I have a problem in outputing JSON from my ws project. Here the source code.

Controller

```
@RestController
```

public class Controller {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  @ResponseBody
String sample(@PathVariable String name) {
    String temp = name;
     return temp;
}
```

}

web. xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <!-- set forceEncoding to true if you want to override encoding of servlet -->
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.package" />
```

In my pom.xml, I already have a jackson for JSON.

When i try to run  "localhost:8081/projectName/param".. It didn't output anything. Am I missing a piece of my code. Please help.

Comment: did not output anything: does that refer to the browser or curl? have you had a look at the network request / response with firebug or the chrome developer tools? It seems you need to query /sample/somename and not /param. Or was that just an example?

Comment: actually i am using postman to get the expected output and yes /sample/param is just an example.